# MapKit User Location (Blue Dot & Circle) will not show

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4, mapkit, android-mapview

I cannot figure out why the current location circle will not appear. I have custom annotations that appear just fine... and the map is taken to the current location of the user... but, the circle is not appearing.

Here is my code. Thanks in advance!

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

 locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
 [locationManager setDelegate:self];
 [locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
 [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

 [mapView setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
 mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;

 MKCoordinateRegion region = { {0.0, 0.0 }, { 0.0, 0.0 } };
 region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.005;
 region.span.latitudeDelta = 0.005;
 [mapView setRegion:region animated:YES]; 
 [mapView setDelegate:self];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation  {
    CLLocationCoordinate2D loc = [newLocation coordinate];
    [mapView setCenterCoordinate:loc];      
    }

-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)map viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    static NSString *AnnotationViewID = @"annotationViewID";
    MKAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:AnnotationViewID];

    if (annotationView == nil) {
        annotationView = [[[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:AnnotationViewID] autorelease];
        }

    annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;

    if ([annotationView.annotation.title isEqualToString:@"One"]) {
        UIImage *pinImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"one.png"];
        [annotationView setImage:pinImage];
    }

    if ([annotationView.annotation.title isEqualToString:@"Two"]) {
        UIImage *pinImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"two.png"];
        [annotationView setImage:pinImage];
    }

    annotationView.annotation = annotation;
        return annotationView;

    }
```

Comment: Are you testing on the device or in simulator? In simulator the users location is always in Cupertino, CA.

Comment: Show your viewForAnnotation method.

Comment: @ezekielDFM I'm using both a device and the simulator. The user location won't appear in Cupertino either. @aBitObvious I updated my original question.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Add this to the top of the viewForAnnotation method:

```
if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
    return nil;  //return nil to use default blue dot view
```

Comment: @Anna Karenina In Device, blinking circle is not appearing but just display blue dot for current location and in simulator its working fine so please give me idea for that